# Searching the plant names in a text file using python

Tags: python, search

I want to search all the plant names that are in this text file that I have made using the code below. I do not have a list of plant names or a specific plant name. Is there a way to search and display for all/every plant name in the text file?

```
from nltk.stem.porter import *
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
ps = PorterStemmer()
f = open("5.txt")
text = f.read()
f.close
new_text = word_tokenize(text)
with open("V Token.txt","w") as f:
    for w in new_text:
        print(w, file=f)
```

Comment: I am not following. How would you know if the text your function returns is a plant name? What criteria are you using to distinguish plant names from other random text?

Comment: That's what I am trying to figure out. Is there a way/library of doing that? means automatically distinguishing the word as a plant name???

Comment: Unless you have a database of plant names somewhere to reference, of you have a trained neural network function (that was trained on a database of plant names), then no, machines don't automatically know what plant names are.

Comment: I did a google search for you. Here is an example of someone writing code to pull plant names from a website so that they can determine plant names from non plant names: https://github.com/petergpython/CheckPlantName/blob/master/checkPlantName.py

Comment: Or if this is not possible, then If I have a List of plant names in a separate file, How will i check it against this text file (5.txt) to find the number of occurrences ???

Comment: Thanks Bobby. Now if I have My list of PlantNames.txt, How will i check it against this text file (5.txt) to find the number of occurrences ???

Comment: Well there are a number of ways to do that. If your list is small, then you might just load the file and check if the name shows up on the list. If you are planning on using this function millions of times, then you would probably want to make a hash table or something to speed up the checking. It depends on how many plant names you are talking about and how many times you plan on using the function.

Comment: Should not this question be downvoted? I'm really asking. If not, why?